# Manipulate state with prevState in react hooks,

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an object that I am store into the data state in react hooks.

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
```

the data looks like that:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1mvO.png)

What I want to achieve is that I will return the data state the same except that I need to filter selected_process by process_id, for example: removing the first object with process_id 419.

edit:

I tried to do:

```
setData((prevData) => prevData.order.selected_process.filter(item => item.process_id !== process_id));
```

but than data looks like that:

[image: data]

Instead to have all the data + the filtered data I am getting only the filtered data.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u want to change the data and rmove one item from a list u can do it like so whenever u want in the code..:

```
function Comp(){
    const [data, setData] = useState();
    
    function setTheList(unwantedItemId){
        setData(prevData=>({...prevData,
                order : { ...prevData.order ,
                     selected_process : 
      prevData.order.selected_process.filter(item=>
                           item.id!==unwantedItemId
                          )
    }}))
    }
    //... your code 
    

    reutrn <OtherComp/>
}
```

this answer is a working solution but it seems like your state need some sort of refactoring to be able to change it in some easier ways... i would suggest to split the state to many states...

Comment: Thanks for replying,
Maybe I didn't explain myself well, the data that I am getting from axios get request is already stored in data state that is not the problem, I want to filter just one selected process based on the process_id from the data and setData again without the selected_process.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean but there is a small problem, what I did is

setData((prevData) =>
            prevData.order.selected_process.filter(
              item => item.process_id !== process_id
);

And now data looks like that :

data: {
0: {process_id: 419..........}
}

Instead to have all the data + the filtered data I have only the filtered data.